# AWS APIs to test current permissions for a resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-cli, amazon-glacier

I'm building a command line tool to automate a few routine tasks. One of the tasks is to upload a directory to Glacier.

How can I test using AWS APIs that provided aws key and secret belong to a user with certain actions for a certain vault allowed i.e.

Actions `CreateVault`, `InitiateMultipartUpload`, `UploadMultipartPart` are allowed for `arn:aws:glacier:eu-west-1:12324:vault` resource.

Comment: Why not just try the API call and catch the appropriate permission exception. You can then handle the failure case as per whatever logic you like.

Comment: I want to minimize the risk of getting permission error mid way as rollback and recovery will not be a trivial task.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear, I meant you might try making the API call and catching the exception as part of your test functionality, not as part of your CLI.

Comment: I'd rather avoid change requests on production data to test permissions tbh. I agree that this will work in some cases (including mine to be fair) but I was hoping there is a cleaner solution.